# Excel VB, Auto show area when shape change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How could I auto-refresh the area calculated when I change the shape dimension.
My current coding as below:

```
Sub ShowArea()
    Dim Width As Single
    Dim Height As Single

    Width = Selection.ShapeRange(1).Width / 72
    Height = Selection.ShapeRange(1).Height / 72

     With Selection.ShapeRange(1)

            Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame.Characters.Text = Round(Width * Height, 1)

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't have built-in events for shapes.

You can try this add-in which offers the desired functionality: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/02/21/excel-shapes-events/

(I haven't tried it yet, just found on the internet)

Once you'll have this events, you can simply move your code into it.